# Brightspot @Renderer.LayoutPath

Tags: jsp

I'm new to Brightspot and I am working my way through the hello world tutorial. There is an annotation within this tutorial as follows:

`@Renderer.LayoutPath("/render/page-container.jsp")`

I have created the file `page-container.jsp` but I have no idea where I should create the folder `/render` as there is no description in the tutorial of where it should point to within the project. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've already figured it out at this point but if not, within the Maven project you'll want to put the jsp in `src/main/webapp/render/page-container.jsp`